# How to use community HTTP plugin in a Ionic React app when running the app on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I’m working on an Ionic React App running on top of Capacitor. It works fine with axios requests in browser, but on Android I have `CORS` issues, that’s why I’m using the `community HTTP plugin`:https://github.com/capacitor-community/http

Example: I click on my Login button. My data such as email and password are supposed to be sent via HTTP post, but it catches the error I have put there: Try again’ .

**Do you have any idea why it might happen?**

No error logs regarding the request on Android Studio either. Only these:

```
    /system_process E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
    E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the ‘pipe:qemud:network’ service: Invalid argument
    E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe ‘qemud:network’: Invalid argument
    E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the ‘pipe:qemud:wififorward’ service: Invalid argument
    E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
```

To solve these errors I have added this setting inside `application` element:

```
    android:usesCleartextTraffic=“true”
```

but the errors still occur.

Android emulator is connected to Internet.

```
<!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <!-- Network API -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Login.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import MyContext from "../my-context";
import {
  IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
  IonInput,
  IonLabel,
  IonItem,
  IonGrid,
  IonCol,
  IonAlert,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { Http, HttpResponse } from "@capacitor-community/http";

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const {
    email,
    setEmail,
    password, 
    setPassword
  } = useContext(MyContext);

     const doLogin = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const loginData = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    //https://github.com/capacitor-community/http
    const options = {
      url: "https://xx/login,
      data: loginData,
    };
    const response: HttpResponse = await Http.post(options)

      .then((response) => {

        if (response.data.token) {
          history.push("/home");
          window.location.reload();
        }
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage(
          "Try again!"
        );
      setIserror(true);
      });
    };

return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding ion-text-center">
        <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonAlert
                isOpen={iserror}
                onDidDismiss={() => setIserror(false)}
                header={"Info!"}
                message={message}
                buttons={["Ok"]}
              />
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
         
                <h1>Login</h1>
              </IonCardTitle>
          
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating">Email</IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  value={email}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setEmail(e.detail.value!)}
                />
              </IonItem>

              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating">Password</IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={password}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}
                />
              </IonItem>
             
              <IonButton onClick={doLogin}>Login</IonButton>
             
        </IonGrid>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I’m stuck with this issue since 3 days, so any help would be really, really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found the solution. In this doc https://github.com/capacitor-community/http, **configuration for Android** is missing.

1- So, import and `add http plugin` in `android\app\src\main\java\\MainActivity.java`

```
package com.myapp.com;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.getcapacitor.plugin.http.Http; //added

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
      add(Http.class); //added
    }});
  }
}
```

2- Sync gradle files in Android Studio:

```
File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

I wrote the request according to my needs and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Has the server received the HTTP request? You can try to print log for judgment.

So that we can proceed to the next step

Comment: I don't have access in API server side. I'm accessing an external API. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I added the full Login component in the question. Please take a look there. The idea is that when I access the external API with the right credentials, this API will return a response containing a token. If the response contains that token, I can access Home page. Otherwise, an alert will be showing telling me to try again. I'm accessing the API request with the right credentials. This works fine in the browser where I'm using axios request. On android, I'm not using axios, I'm using http plugin to avoid CORS. but it fails.

Comment: I can't find out the reason， i ' m so sorry